# Datatable JSON Formatting error

Tags: angularjs, datatable

Hi I am getting this warning message even though the results are showing in rows

> DataTables warning (table id = 'list'): DataTables warning: JSON data from server could not be parsed. This is caused by a JSON formatting error

while trying to invoking a web service call using angularjs and loading the results in Datatable.Here is my controller.js

```
var clustersApp = angular.module('clustersApp', []);

clustersApp.controller("nodeListCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
$http.get('http:demo.json').then(function(res){
$scope.listData = res.data.nodes;
}); 
});
```

and datatable js

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
$("#list").dataTable({       
    "sPaginationType":"full_numbers",
    "bFilter": true,
    "bInfo": true,
    "bServerSide": true,       
    "oLanguage": {
        "sSearch": "",          
    },               
   "fnPreDrawCallback": function(oSettings,json) {
           $('.dataTables_filter input').addClass('form-control input-sm');
           $('.dataTables_filter input').attr('placeholder', 'Enter Ip to search');                   
    },         
    "asStripClasses": [],
    "aoColumnDefs": [{
        "bSortable": false,
        "aTargets": ["no-sort"]
    }]
});
});
```

Can any one please let me know why is it showing the error.Am very new to JSON.Please help me in sorting the issue.